# How do you create a localhost web server on Windows

Tags: web-hosting, web-development

I want to have a local web server.  There I will install WordPress and add content. After 6 months I will purchase a hosting server & domain and upload to that.

What steps do I need to follow to get the server up and running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you will need an apache server with database support to succesfully install wordpress.

Without knowing your operating system it's hard to say what you'll need, but I'll assume you have a supported version of Windoze.

You can use [Web Pi to install wordpress on IIS](https://blogs.iis.net/peterviola/installing-wordpress-php-and-mysql-on-windows-server-2012-r2).

But one of the easiest options is to [use ampps](http://www.ampps.com/) which is by the people who created softaculous which automates wordpress and other script installations very easily.

Here's a [tutorial](http://www.ampps.com/wiki/Install) on how to install it.

And when you're ready to move on to a hosted service you can just migrate it using ftp or one of the many free Wordpress plugins available.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can try use one of these two local machine emulators:

Both are excelent. They come with Apache, PhP, and MySQL for your WP databases. All you need. After download and installation there are alot of tutorials on interwebz where you can setup your db for wordpress and do your work. Good luck, cheers

[WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)

[XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html)